# Навигация (перемотка) по большим Аудиофайлам и использование OЗУ

Tags: java, аудио, io

Пытаюсь сделать музыкальный Mp3-плеер, возникли вопросы по поводу реализации перемотки музыкального трека использую методы mark,reset,skip для (AudioInputStream), но при работе с большими аудиофайлами используется очень много озу.

Получается что вся дорожка загружается в оп-память? 
Или я что-то делаю не так как надо?

В общем на помощь...

Для работы с mp3 использую

http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html

(jl1.0.1,mp3spi1.9.5,tritonus_share)

```
public class MainClass {

static long HowManySkip = 0;
static long FileLeg = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[5000];

    ///////////////// GUI/////////////
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    JProgressBar prb = new JProgressBar();
    prb.setMaximum(100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 70);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.add(prb);

    prb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            HowManySkip = (long) Map(e.getX(), 0, 400, 0, FileLeg);

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
    //////////////////////////////////

    try {
        File f = new File("test.mp3");
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);

        FileLeg = in.available();
        in.mark(in.available());


        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, in.getFormat().getSampleRate(),16, 2, 4, 44100.0f, true);

        AudioInputStream din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, decodedFormat);
        SourceDataLine Output = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        Output.open(decodedFormat);
        Output.start();

        while (num != -1) {
            // Прогресс бар
            prb.setValue((int) (100 - Map(in.available(), 0, FileLeg, 0, 100)));

            Output.write(data, 0, num);

            if (HowManySkip != 0) {
                Output.stop();
                in.reset();
                while (HowManySkip != 0) {
                    HowManySkip -= in.skip(HowManySkip);
                }
                Output.drain();
                Output.start();
            }

            num = din.read(data);
            Thread.sleep(20);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static double Map(double n, double start1, double stop1, double start2, double stop2) {
    return ((n - start1) / (stop1 - start1)) * (stop2 - start2) + start2;

 }

}
```